# What is the meaning of input path in the order of module search path in python?

Tags: python-3.x

> When the interpreter executes the above import statement, it searches
> for mod.py in a list of directories assembled from the following
> sources:
>
> The directory from which the input script was run or the current
> directory if the interpreter is being run interactively
>
> The list of directories contained in the PYTHONPATH environment variable, if it is
> set. (The format for PYTHONPATH is OS-dependent but should mimic the
> PATH environment variable.)
>
> An installation-dependent list of
> directories configured at the time Python is installed

What is the meaning of "The directory from which the input script was run"? Is this the directory containing the invoked python file or is it the directory from which the python call is made?

Comment: It also says to achieve this - "Put mod.py in the directory where the input script is located" - So this is not the directory from which the python call is made, its the directory containing the .py file that is executed? Reference: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#the-module-search-path

Comment: Yes, those two descriptions seem to contradict another. I elaborated in an answer. I actually got confused myself and wrote the wrong thing in my first comment, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I find the description misleading. The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) is clearer in my opinion:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

You can easily test this by adding the following script:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

to a subdirectory, then calling it from the parent directory. The first entry of the module search path will be the subdirectory.